# Adicionar valor de uma variável em um registro

Tags: variáveis, bat, echo

criei uma bat para adicionar um conteúdo de um arquivo em um valor de registro, porém não consigo pegar o conteúdo da variável jogar no valor.

Essa é minha .BAT

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If exist "MD5arquivo.TXT" del MD5arquivo.TXT
set /a cont=0
for /f "delims= skip=4" %%a in (C:\commerce\MD5-PAF-ECF-LINX.TXT) do (
echo %%a>> MD5arquivo.TXT
set /p var=<MD5arquivo.TXT
set /a cont=!cont!+1
if "!cont!"=="2" goto novo
pause
)

:novo
reg add HKLM\Software\RegisteredApplications /v "MD5-PAF-ECF-LINX.TXT" /d %var%
```

ao jogar o conteúdo da variável %var% no registro é apresentado o erro abaixo

[image: Erro]

Ao utilizar o comando echo para mostrar o conteúdo da minha variável, percebo que o conteúdo dela é o que eu preciso, conforme retorno abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

Perdão, mas to achando que você complicou sua lógica/código...

Seria bom adicionar o conteúdo do seu arquivo `MD5-PAF-ECF-LINX.TXT`, só para ter uma melhor idéia do que busca atingir com seu bat..

Idependente do layout/conteúdo de seu arquivo, tente:

```
@echo off 

cd/d "%~dp0"
for /f usebackq^tokens^=*skip^=5 %%a in (`type "C:\commerce\MD5-PAF-ECF-LINX.TXT"`
    `)do reg add HKLM\Software\RegisteredApplications /v "MD5-PAF-ECF-LINX.TXT" /t REG_DWORD d "%%~a" /f & goto :novo

:novo
```

- Observações:

`skip^=4` vai pular 4 linhas, remova o contador e use `Skip^=5` ou 6 se for o caso
`if "String" == "String"`  use aspas e "==" é para cadeias de caratcer na sua comparação
`if Números equ 9999999`  use `equ/lss/leq/gtr/geq/etc...` nas comparações númericas
`%var%` use direto a variavél em loop `%%~a`, não precisa/deletar/escrever/ler/setar arquivo algum
`/t REG_DWORD ... /f` considere informar o tipo de entrada e suprimir confirmações

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, o conteúdo do meu arquivo é esse:

; SlavaSoft Optimizing Checksum Utility - fsum 2.52.00337 <www.slavasoft.com>
;
; Generated on 06/22/21 at 16:49:36 
;
d6bd331a7ae1570912bc45228580fc6f *EXECUTAVEIS-LINX.TXT


Essa lógica montada é para pegar os dados da última linha, que é o dado que preciso jogar no meu registro, esse arquivo é modificado constantemente, porém o resultado sempre vem na ultima linha, por isso use daquela forma.

Vou tentar usando seu método.

Comment: @Daniel Edite sua pergunta e adicione linha por linha do seu arquivo

Comment: Se vc tens o arquivo, pq não usar o certuil.exe (já tem Windows) e pegar o hash direto. Sem qualquer arquivo de texto adicional...